# A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, screenshot

I'm trying to make a fullscreen screencapture and load it into an pictureBox, but it's giving me this error:
*A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
Additional information: Ongeldige parameter.*

Code:

```
    using (Bitmap bmpScreenCapture = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenCapture))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                             Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                             0, 0,
                             bmpScreenCapture.Size,
                             CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        }

        pictureBox1.Image = bmpScreenCapture;
    }
```

Joery.

Comment: Which call is giving you the error?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson pictureBox1.Image = bmpScreenCapture;

Comment: A first chance exception is not necessarily bad, take a look a [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx). Does this code of yours actually throw an exception or crash?

Comment: You may want to rethink the `using` that Disposes the bitmap when it's set as a PictureBox Image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exception occurs because the `using` statement disposes of the Bitmap after it's assigned to `pictureBox1.Image`, so the PictureBox is unable to display the bitmap when it's time to repaint itself:

```
using (Bitmap bmpScreenCapture = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height))
{
    // ...

    pictureBox1.Image = bmpScreenCapture;
} // <== bmpScreenCapture.Dispose() gets called here.

// Now pictureBox1.Image references an invalid Bitmap.
```

To fix the problem, keep the Bitmap variable declaration and initializer, but remove the `using`:

```
Bitmap bmpScreenCapture = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                     Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

// ...

pictureBox1.Image = bmpScreenCapture;
```

You should still make sure the Bitmap gets disposed eventually, but only when you truly don't need it anymore (for example, if you replace `pictureBox1.Image` by another bitmap later).

Answer (score 4):

You are disposing the wrong bitmap.  You should dispose the *old* image, the one you replaced, not the one you just created.  Failure to do this correctly, other than crashing your program when the image is painted, will *eventually* bomb your program with this exception when it runs out of memory.  As you found out.  Fix:

```
var bmpScreenCapture = new Bitmap(...);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenCapture)) {
    g.CopyFromScreen(...);
}
if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();      // <=== here!!
pictureBox1.Image = bmpScreenCapture;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it, it will work

```
  pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(sourceBitmap);
```